# Is there a general term for Jedi and Sith?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-force, sith, lightsaber

Is there a term for the Jedi *and* Sith?

I mean if you don't know if the person is a Jedi or a Sith, but you know the person is using a lightsaber and has a big knowledge about the force, what a term are you using?

Comment: Force-sensitive heathen?

Comment: @Trollwut sounds good, but this isn't the term i'm looking for, because if you search it on Google, you don't really find anything... Anyhow good proposition :)

Comment: @Trollwut: we prefer “Midi-chlamericans”.

Comment: Seems like my terminology was as politically incorrect as Senator Palpatine.

Comment: Is the lightsaber bit a requirement?  I hate to get overly technical, but it is a huge difference between between the question and phantom42's answer.  One is a universal term for beings who potential could be either Jedi or Sith, the other is one who has had training in either.  I don't know if there is a neutral term for the latter.

Comment: Ben was referred to as "some old wizard" in a new hope

Comment: The Force Kin..

Answer (score 30):

At the broadest definition, you're simply looking for **Force Sensitive or Forceful**.

Per [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force-sensitive):

> A Force-sensitive, also known as a Forceful, was a being who was highly attuned to the flow of the Force. Force-sensitives could, with training, learn to sense and manipulate the Force.

If you want to get more specific, and qualify that they are more than just sensitive to the Force, the person can be defined as a **Force User** ignoring whether or not they belong to a faction. If you want to assign them a grouping based on their allegiance, you might go with **Force Adept** or **Dark Side Adept** for Jedi or Sith respectively.

> The terms Force-user and Force-sensitive were distinct in meaning. Force-sensitive denoted anyone with Force power, latent or active, while being called a Force-user implied that the individual had at least some understanding and control of their abilities and was able to use them to accomplish specific tasks. The latter was also used in a more specific sense as a general term for Force-trained individuals who did not belong to either of the two major Force traditions, the Jedi and the Sith. Another term for Force-user was Force Adept, for dark-siders sometimes Dark Side Adept (not to be confused with the Imperial title and organization proper).

Comment: Force Sensitive and Force User are also the terms used in Star Wars RPG book series to refer to such characters as Force Users - putting together Jedi, Sith and "unaligned" people with force powers.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the term Jedi/Sith would be appropriate. And according to star wars rebels, there are things in between.